How to Handle transaction with Nextjs 14 and Drizzle ORM
I am developing an application using Next.js 14, Drizzle ORM, and NeonDB/PostgreSQL, and I'm encountering issues when running transaction queries.
Here’s a simplified version of my setup:
Database Initialization (src/db/drizzle.ts):
import { config } from "dotenv";
import { drizzle } from "drizzle-orm/neon-http";
import * as schema from "./schema";
config({ path: ".env" }); // or .env.local
export const db = drizzle(process.env.DATABASE_URL!, { schema });

Drizzle Config (drizzle.config.ts):
import { config } from "dotenv";
import { defineConfig } from "drizzle-kit";
config({ path: ".env" });
export default defineConfig({
  schema: "./src/db/schema.ts",
  out: "./drizzle/migrations",
  dialect: "postgresql",
  dbCredentials: {
    url: process.env.DATABASE_URL!,
  },
});

Transaction Query:
const data = await tx.transaction(async (tx) => {
  const productIdResult = await tx.insert(products).values({ type: "music" }).returning({ id: products.id });
  const productId = productIdResult[0].id;
  await tx.insert(music).values({ ...product, id: productId });
  await tx.insert(musicCategories).values(categoryIds);
  return productId;
});

When I run the above transaction query, I get the following error:
No transactions support in neon-http driver

After some research, I found this article, which mentions using Neon’s Pool and Client for transactions. However, I am unsure how to integrate this approach into my setup with Next.js and Drizzle ORM.
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

update drizzle.ts with the following code
import { Pool } from '@neondatabase/serverless';
import { drizzle } from 'drizzle-orm/neon-serverless';
import * as schema from "./schema";
const pool = new Pool({ connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL });
export const db = drizzle({ client: pool,schema: schema })

